# How to force-detect network devices with Network Manager under Linux

Tags: linux, networking, networkmanager

I usually get connected to internet with a mobile broadband connection, provided by my Nokia 5800 phone linked to my computer with its USB cable.

I'm using Network Manager (on Kubuntu 12.04 with KDE 4.10.2), and sometimes, when I plug in the phone, even if it correctly detected *by the system* (it is listed in the removable devices list), it is not seen from *Network Manager*.
Usually it happens when I re-plug it in, during  a running session, after I had to disconnect it from the computer.

I would like to know if it is possible to have Network Manager (even with the command line interface with `nmcli`) perform a scan for devices, in order to force-detect it.
As things stands right now, to have it detected again I have to completely reboot the system (a simple session quit isn't working either), but it is not a viable solution; there should be a proper way to solve this issue without having to close the current session.

Any clues?

Comment: There is no way to "scan for devices" in general. the Linux kernel works with events, so does udev (you have maybe noticed boot messages such as "waiting for udev to synthesize events..."), gudev and finally, network manager.  Why don't you ask us for the original problem instead ?

Comment: Well, the problem is that the phone is not detected, like I said. I need a way to make NM recognize it in order to use it, without having to reboot the system. If not by "scanning", by any other mean, I just need a working solution.